# Strange behavior with dates in C

Tags: c, date, pointers

Here is what I have:

```
struct test_date {
    time_t t;
    pid_t pid;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    dates = malloc(CHILDREN_LIMIT * sizeof(struct test_date*)); // an array declared static of type struct test_date
    //... later
    struct test_date *td = &dates[children]; //children is a counter
    if (fork() == 0) { // in a child process
        td->pid = getpid();
        time(&(td->t));
        //now, if I print the date, I get a strange result. look bellow for get_time function.
        printf("%s\n", get_time(&td->t));
        //...
    }
    //...
    exit(0);
}

char *get_time(time_t *t) {

    struct tm *bt = malloc(sizeof(struct tm*));
    char *strt = malloc(DATE_SIZE * sizeof(char *));

    localtime_r(t, bt);
    strftime(strt, 100, "%Y-%m-%d %T", bt);
    return strt;
}
```

The output for this code:

eg. It should be: 2013-07-16 09:21:28

But it is: 2013-858861619-16 09:21:28

Even more, if I call the same `printf` function later, in some functions called from child process, I get an even worse result. A date somewhere to 1974.

Can anybody tell me where is my mistake? I guess it should be where I pass the `time_t` variable as pointer, but I can't understand why this behavior. Can anybody detail on this topic?

Comment: Malloc(CHILDREN_LIMIT * sizeof(struct test_date))

Comment: It is from 1st Jan 1970.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct tm *bt = malloc(sizeof(struct tm*));
char *strt = malloc(DATE_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
```

should be:

```
struct tm *bt = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
char *strt = malloc(DATE_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

In the `main`:

```
dates = malloc(CHILDREN_LIMIT * sizeof(struct test_date*));
```

should be

```
dates = malloc(CHILDREN_LIMIT * sizeof(struct test_date));
```

I think you may have a mis-understanding of the usage of `malloc`, check out a manual, and use this safer form, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/using-sizeofpointer-in-malloc-why) for detail:

```
struct tm* bt = malloc(sizeof(*bt));
```

Answer (score 1):

The struct `tm` you are allocating is too small.

It should be

```
struct tm *bt = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
```

`strftime` write some data into memory that was no allocated by malloc which could be part of another allocated chunk of memory, maybe that of **strt**. This could cause the strange values. The same also applies to allocation of `dates` array.