# Is there anything wrong with `something_t* x = malloc(sizeof(*x))`?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, sizeof

I'm writing some extremely repetitive code in C (reading XML), and I found that writing my code like makes it easier to copy and paste code in a constructor*:

```
something_t* something_new(void)
{
    something_t* obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
    /* initialize */
    return obj;
}
```

What I'm wondering is, it is safe to use `sizeof(*obj)` like this, when I just defined `obj`? GCC isn't showing any warnings and the code works fine, but GCC tends to have "helpful" extensions so I don't trust it.

* And yes, I realize that I should have just written a Python program to write my C program, but it's almost done already.

Comment: You can even omit the brackets: `(sizeof *obj)` if you like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it safer to use sizeof(\*pointer) in malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/why-is-it-safer-to-use-sizeofpointer-in-malloc)

Comment: This is even [the recommended way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/) precisely because you can easily see that you have allocated the right amount

Comment: People keep answering different questions in the answers, and answering my question in the comments :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> something_t* obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
> ```
>
> What I'm wondering is, it is safe to use `sizeof(*obj)`
>   like this, when I just defined `obj`?

You have a *declaration* consisting of:

- *type-specifier* `something_t`
- *declarator* `* obj`
- `=`
- *initializer* `malloc(sizeof(*obj))`
- `;`

The C standard says in section **Scopes of identifiers**:

> Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
>   after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>   tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. Any other
>   identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its
>   declarator.

Since `obj` *has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator*, it is guaranteed by the standard that the identifier used in the *initializer* refers to the just defined object.

Answer (score 0):

While we are giving the sizeof like this.

```
something_t* obj = malloc(sizeof(obj));
```

It will allocate the memory to  that pointer variable as four bytes( bytes allocated to a pointer variable.)

```
something_t* obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
```

It will take the data type which is declared to that pointer.

For example,

```
char *p;
printf("%d\n",sizeof(p));
```

It will return the value as four.

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(*p));
```

Now it will return value as one. Which is a byte allocated to the character. So when we are using the *p in sizeof it will take the datatype. I don't know this is the answer you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, my example code is doing `sizeof(*obj)`, not `sizeof(obj)` for exactly this reason..

Comment: I just don't think you're answering my question. I already know that I should do `sizeof(*obj)`.

Comment: @BrendanLong Ok, I apologize. But I am not know clearly what you are expecting!.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe. For example,

```
n = sizeof(*(int *)NULL);
```

In this case, NULL pointer access doesn't occur, because a compiler can caluculate the size of the operand without knowing the value of  "*(int *)NULL" in run time.

The C89/90 standard guarantees the 'sizeof' expression is a constant one; it is translated into a constant (e.g. 0x04) and embedded into a binary code in compilation stage.

In C99 standard, the 'sizeof' expression is not always a compile-time constant, because of introducing variable length array. For example,

```
n = sizeof(int [*(int *)NULL]);
```

In this case, the value of "*(int *)NULL" needs to be known in run time to caluculate the size of 'int[]'.

Comment: We are only talking about the case `sizeof *variable_name` though

Comment: In the case of ｀sizeof *obj｀ or ｀sizeof *(T *)NULL｀ , you know,  any pointer access doesn't occur in C89/90 standard. In that respect, it doesn't matter whether variable name or immediate value is assiged.