# c - realloc() on tokenized array: signal SIGABRT error

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays, realloc, sigabrt

On line 56, I'm trying to resize an array:

```
tokenArray = (char**) realloc(tokenArray, tokSize * (sizeof(char)));
```

I get an error:

> (11972,0x7fff7ca4f300) malloc: *** error for object 0x100105598: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

This is a programming assignment for a class, I have been specifically instructed to dynamically allocated my arrays, and then expand as needed. I have searched extensively for another thread on the same that isn't too advanced for me to understand, no luck yet... So hopefully I can get some help. Thanks! Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ROW_SIZE 81

void strInput(char str[], int numElem);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Enter a string of any number of integers separated by spaces or tabs.\n");
    printf("Maximum string length is 80 characters.\n");
    printf("Enter an empty string to conclude input.\n");


    int arrSize = 10, tokSize = 10, i = 0, j = 0;

    char** inputArray = malloc(arrSize * (sizeof(char)));
    char** tokenArray = malloc(tokSize * (sizeof(char)));


    do {
        inputArray[i] = malloc(MAX_ROW_SIZE * sizeof(int));

        strInput(inputArray[i], arrSize);

        if ((inputArray[i][0] != '\0') && (i == (arrSize - 1)))
        {
            arrSize = arrSize * 2;
            inputArray = (char**) realloc(inputArray, arrSize * (sizeof(char)));
        }

        while (inputArray[i][j] != '\0')
        {
            printf("%c", inputArray[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;

        i++;
    } while (inputArray[i-1][0] != '\0');

    i = 0;

    while (inputArray[i][0] != '\0')
    {

        if ((tokenArray[j] = strtok(inputArray[i], " \t")))
            j++;
        while ((tokenArray[j] = strtok(NULL, " \t")))
        {
            if (j == (tokSize - 1))
            {
                tokSize = 2 * tokSize;

 //This is the line where I get the error
                tokenArray = (char**) realloc(tokenArray, tokSize * (sizeof(char)));
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("printing the tokenized arrays: ");
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        printf("%s ", tokenArray[i]);

    free(inputArray);
    free(tokenArray);

    return 0;
}

void strInput(char str[], int numElem)
{


    int j, k = 0;

    j = k;

    while ((str[k] = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        k++;
    }

    if (str[k] == '\n')
        str[k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: One thing that worries me is that `tokenArray` is a pointer to pointer to `char`, but you're only allocating using `sizeof(char)` and not `sizeof(char *)`. So your initial allocation is an array of ten *characters* and not ten pointers to character.

Comment: As mentioned by @JoachimPileborg, this: `char** inputArray = malloc(arrSize * (sizeof(char)));` should be `char** inputArray = malloc(arrSize * sizeof *inputArray);`. That protects you from yourself, and makes the allocation have the proper size. This pattern always works.

Comment: Wow... that's all it was! Thanks a lot both of you! I really try to post on here as an absolute last resort :D

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly... because arrays are naturally pointers to addresses, when I was allocating my arrays I was allocating them to the size of 'char' even though they would actually be holding an address... so 'char *' will give the size of an address?

Comment: Warning: You [should not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the return of malloc. Second warning: when calling `sizeof` in `malloc` (and the like) [you should always write it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17258659/1151654) as `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ...);` instead of `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptrtype*) * ...);`.

Comment: `because arrays are naturally pointers to addresses` that's not true. You made an array out of  `char*`-pointers, yes, but it's also possible to make an array of `char`, `int`, `struct` and any other type.

Answer (score 5):

#### [1. Do not cast the result of `malloc` and friends.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393)

It's useless at best and dangerous at worst.

#### 2. Mind the size you are `malloc`'ing.

```
char** inputArray = malloc(arrSize * (sizeof(char)));
```

This makes no sense, and is probably accidental. As a rule of thumb, the type you are `malloc`'ing for and the pointer you're pointing at the resulting storage should differ by only one indirection. I.e :

```
char** inputArray = malloc(arrSize * sizeof(char*));
//  ^^ Double-pointer     vs     Single pointer ^
```

Better rule of thumb yet, let the compiler figure it out. `sizeof` can deduce the type it should measure from an expression.

```
char **inputArray = malloc(arrSize * sizeof(*inputArray));
```

This works because the operand of `sizeof` is an unevaluated context. The pointer won't actually be dereferenced, only its type will be deduced.
Side note : `sizeof`'s parentheses are not needed around an expression, but I've left them for clarity. Remove them once you're comfortable with it.

#### 3. Check that allocation was successful.

`malloc` and friends will return `NULL` in case of trouble. You should check for that.

#### 4. Fix your `realloc`

```
inputArray = realloc(inputArray, /*...*/);
```

This is wrong. As mentioned above, if `realloc` fails, it will return `NULL` *and do nothing else*. This means that `inputArray` still points at its previous storage. That is, until you trump this pointer with the `NULL` `realloc` just returned, and leak said storage. Oops.

Always store, check, and *then* assign the result of `realloc`.

```
char **inputArray_ = realloc(inputArray, /*...*/);
if(!inputArray_) {
    /* Allocation failure, handle it and break out */
}
inputArray = inputArray_;
```