# Trouble with malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following struct

```
struct NETWORK_ENDPOINT {
  unsigned char Type;
  unsigned char Protocol;
  unsigned char IPv4[IPV4SIZE + 1];
  unsigned int PortNumber;

  unsigned char SocketIndex;
  unsigned char RESERVED;
  unsigned char *InboundData;
  unsigned int InboundDataSize;

  unsigned char *OutboundData;
  unsigned int OutboundDataSize;
};
```

In the code I'm allocating with :

```
struct NETWORK_ENDPOINT *Endpoint = malloc(sizeof(struct NETWORK_ENDPOINT));
```

Then later in the code I'm allocating the OutboundData with.

```
Endpoint->OutboundData = malloc(20); // malloc() size may vary, 
                                     // but in the problem situation it is 20
```

Then I do :

```
memcpy(Endpoint->OutboundData, Data, 20);
```

Then the problem : From the debugger I can see that `Endpoint` is given address @0x1fd6, and the `OutboundData` is given address @0x1fca, so only 12 between. Shouldn't is be atleast 20 ?

The `memcpy()` function then will fill out in `OutboundData` ( can see in memory that data is correctly placed ), but once it passes 12 bytes, it will begin overwriting the start of the struct `Endpoint`, corrupting the `Type` and `Protocol` and half the `IP`, thereby making it useless afterwards.

anyone got any idea what I'm going wrong here ? Been working on this for days now, but whatever I try it does not fix this issue...

Have tried to increase the HEAP size, but it seems to stay at 12 bytes between the two memory locations no matter what I do..

Comment: Warning: when calling `sizeof` in `malloc` (and the like) [you should always write it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17258659/1151654) as `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ...);` instead of `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptrtype*) * ...);`.

Comment: I think this question needs a better title.

Answer (score 5):

> *OutboundData is given address @0x1fca, so only 12 between*

Why you're interested in the *address of* `OutboundData`?

After `malloc()`, you should be checking the *value of* `OutboundData`, however, you won't be knowing the *size* of allocated memory thr' this.

Just to be clear, you're **not** copying *to the address of* `OutboundData`, rather , you are copying *to the address pointed by* `OutboundData`.

Then,

> *but once it passes 12 bytes, it will begin overwriting the start of the struct Endpoint, corrupting the Type and Protocol and half the IP, thereby making it useless afterwards.*

No, it won't. The *value* and *address* of `OutboundData` are different and the *value* of `OutboundData` is used in `memcpy()`.

IMHO, as long as

- `malloc()` is success
- `Data` is atleast of size `20` (for this case)

your `memcpy()` should work fine.

Comment: Reason for mentioning the address of OutboundData, is that it looks like malloc allocates the OutboundData to close to the memory previously allocated to the endpoint struct. After OutboundData = malloc..., Outbound data get's a value ( aka allocation successfull ? ). Endpoint->Outbound data should give me the address ? (*Endpoint).Outbound data = address, *(*Endpoint).OutboundData = first value byte ?

Comment: Or simpler put: unsigned char *A; then A = address, and *A = value ?

Comment: @user1244472 Second comment is perfect.

Comment: Then should not the same apply to the given problem ? So that (*Endpoint).OutboundData = Address `? or Endpoint->OutboundData = Address ?

Comment: @user1244472  think of it this way --> the return value of `malloc()` is stored in `Endpoint->OutboundData`, now, what does `malloc()` return?

Comment: You mentioned in your previous answer that "The value and address of OutboundData are different and the value of OutboundData is used in memcpy().", I read this as I'm not using the correct notation in the memcpy. But I thought that Endpoint->OutboundData was the address pointed to by the Endpoint->OutboundData pointer , not the value ? Or did I misunderstand your meaning ?

Comment: @user1244472 I think I'm the one not able to explain properly. Actually I'm not a native english speaker, so sometimes I mess up. What itried to mean is in the case, `char *p`, `&p` is of type `char **`, `p`  is of type `char *` and `*p` is of type `char`. Hope this make things clear. :-)

Comment: malloc returns a pointer ( void *), that is why I thought that Endpoint->OutboundData would contain a pointer to the memory allocated, thus I can use this in the memcpy as the address of the dest * argument

Comment: @user1244472 that is what i'm saying, your code is fine. There is no logical errors, atleast. The error you're thinking, is not an error in this case, at all.

Comment: Your explanations are just fine, I'm just not getting it :) Tried this &Endpoint->OutboundData and it worked, but I just can't get my mind wrapped around why as I thought that when you use ptr = malloc, the ptr would already contain the address and the & would not be necessary..