# size of array allocated with malloc is showing one less than expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I have this:

```
alloc(Btree *bt, uint8_t *keylen, int16_t n)
{

bt->node[n].key = malloc(sizeof(int16_t)*(*keylen));
{
```

Where `bt->node[n].key` is a pointer to `int16_t`.

With the debugger running, I can verify that `keylen` is `5`.

But if I put:

```
int kl = sizeof(bt->node[n].key) / sizeof(bt->node[n].key[0])
```

`kl` is `4`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Warning: when calling `sizeof` in `malloc` (and the like) [you should write it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17258659/1151654) as `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ...);` instead of `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptrtype*) * ...);`. Here, for instance, you should write `malloc(sizeof(*(bt->node[n].key))*(*keylen));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look carefully, you are confusing the pointer with the array:

> Where bt->node[n].key is a pointer to int16_t.

Thus, bt->node[n].key is a pointer to the allocated memory, not the allocated memory itself, and `sizeof bt->node[n].key` is `sizeof <pointer to ...>` which, in your system is 8 (64 bits).

```
8 / sizeof uint16_t = 8 / 2 = 4
```

You can not check the size of the allocated memory chunk, you have to trust `malloc()` to work well or return `NULL` if it can't.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` operator produces the *size* of a `type`, not the amount of memory *allocated to a pointer*.

In your case, what happenning is

- `key` is of type `int16_t *`
- `sizeof(bt->node[n].key)` gives `sizeof(int16_t *)` which on 64 bit, `8`
- `sizeof(bt->node[n].key[0])` which is `sizeof(int16_t )`, which is `2`

Ultimately,  it's `8/2` = 4.

There is absolutely no measurement of the amount of memory returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(bt->node[n].key)` is `sizeof(uint16_t*)` which could be 8 (on 64 bits)
`sizeof(bt->node[n].key[0])` is `sizeof(*(uint16_t*))` which is 2

And `8 / 2` equals 4.

Comment: `sizeof` counts bytes, not bits.

Comment: @KeithThompson ah yes indeed.