# free() the value of a struct** pointer

Tags: c, list, free

I'm curious about how to delete a struct that I stored in a list.
I tried this code but it gives me a segmentation fault error and I can't see the mistake.

```
typedef struct double_stack_head_struct
{
    struct double_stack_head_struct* tail;
    double                           value;
} double_stack_head;

typedef struct double_stack_struct    // the structure containing the state of a stack
{
    int                size;     // size of stack
    double_stack_head* head;
} double_stack;

void push_double_stack(double_stack* stack, double value)
{
    double_stack_head* new_head = malloc(sizeof(double_stack_head));
    if(new_head != NULL) {
        new_head->tail = stack->head;
        new_head->value = value;

        stack->head = new_head;
        stack->size += 1;
    }
}

int pop_double_stack(double_stack* stack, double* value)
{
    if(empty_double_stack(stack)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        *value = stack->head->value;
        free(stack->head);
        stack->size -= 1;
        stack->head = malloc(sizeof(stack->head));
        stack->head = stack->head->tail;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your pop function calls malloc, then immediately overwrites the saved pointer. This leaks, and may also be the cause of the crash (if the other value isn't also a valid pointer from malloc).

Comment: It also makes little sense to allocate a new head after popping.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `malloc` and `free` should be symmetrical with respect to each other, in that for a given `malloc` call to allocate memory on the heap, there should be a matching `free` call to deallocate it.

If we just glance at your stack logic, your push function allocates a new node. Your pop function frees a node, but it also allocates a new one. So we have something asymmetrical here, and that's going to be a problem.

Another thing to note is that `sizeof(struct Node*)` is different from `sizeof(struct Node)`. When you do `sizeof(stack->head)`, you're actually checking the size of the type of `size->head` which is the size of the pointer rather than the pointee.

However, you don't really want to be allocating new nodes in a pop function, so its your stack logic that you need to correct. When you pop from a singly-linked list like this, you want to capture a pointer to the node for the head (top of the stack), set the head to point to the next element (right below the top of the stack), and free that former head.

Comment: Thanks I had a minor mistake, but you are right. i took a shower and noticed that I have to copy the "tail" which I didnt. Code works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  don't do this!!

  stack->head = malloc(sizeof(stack->head));
```

use this:

```
  stack->head = (double_stack_head *)malloc(sizeof(double_stack_head));
```

also pay attention on the following function

```
 void push_double_stack(double_stack* stack, double value)
```

it creates a reference cycle between double_stack and double_stack_struct

Comment: [casting the return of `malloc` in *C* is not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and [`sizeof(*stack->head);`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/why-is-it-safer-to-use-sizeofpointer-in-malloc) is also preferable to explicitly mentioning the type.