# How to malloc() With Custom Types?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, types

In a header file -- gameboard.h -- I have a struct named **gameboard**. In this struct I declare `square **squares`, where squares is the following: `typedef enum {EMPTY, RED_COIN, YELLOW_COIN} square;`

In gameboard.c, I have a function that allocates memory for a 2D array. In this function I declare `gameboard* result`.

Question: When creating the initial array, i.e. the part of a 2D that will store an array, why can't I do this:

```
result->squares = malloc(numRows * sizeof(result->square*));
```

More specifically, why is **square** an invalid type?

Comment: If `square` is a type name, then what are you trying to say by `result->square`? This just does not make any sense in C. In C `->` is a *member access* operator. And your struct does not have a member named `square`.

Comment: Something like `anytype **` is no 2D array, nor can it point to one! And you should read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "do this" because your `result->square` subexpression is invalid. `result->squares` would be valid. Plain `square` would be valid too. But `result->square` makes no sense at all. In C `->` is a member access operator. And your struct type does not have a member named `square`.

- A typical/idiomatic C code for `malloc`-ing an array of objects would look as follows

  ```
  some_pointer = malloc(n_elements * sizeof *some_pointer);
  ```

  Applying this to your case we get

  ```
  result->squares = malloc(numRows * sizeof *result->squares);
  ```
- If your `result->squares` has type `square **`, then the proper size can also be expressed in terms of `sizeof(array_element_type)` as

  ```
  result->squares = malloc(numRows * sizeof(squares *));
  ```

  But the former (type-agnostic) variant is arguably better than this latter version, specifically for being type-agnostic. See also: [Why is it safer to use sizeof(*pointer) in malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/why-is-it-safer-to-use-sizeofpointer-in-malloc)

How you managed to arrive at `sizeof(result->square*)` is completely unclear to me. Your variant looks like a bizarre hybrid of the two, written in incorrect and meaningless way.

Comment: Also, gameboard.squares is declared as an array of pointer of square. I am not sure if this is the intent.

Comment: @AnT: My class is currently going over pointers and structs and it's apparent there are gaps in my knowledge. After reviewing your comment and my question, I see the many errors made before posting. My next question would be the difference between using malloc() for a 2D array of ints and my case. For example, I would do this for ints: somePtr = malloc(sizeof(int*) * numElements). When dealing with structs, why use squares instead of it's type (square)?

Comment: @KC Wong: The OP stated that the ultimate objective is to create a 2D array. Assuming they are after a typical "jagged array" approach, seeing `squares` declared as a "pointer to pointer" does not looks strange at all.

Comment: @darylnak: `sizeof` has two forms: you can use a *type name* under `sizeof` or you can use an *expression* under `sizeof`. My answer above shows both variants in context of your `malloc`. Both variants will work. However, I would argue for the first - type-independent (or type-agnostic) - variant. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/why-is-it-safer-to-use-sizeofpointer-in-malloc

Comment: @AnT Thank you, I understand now! I may have to look over the text-book again. I did not know I could do this.