# What should I use as the argument of sizeof when malloc

Tags: c

I always confuse about what to put inside of sizeof when malloc

for example,

`struct sth *p = malloc(sizeof(struct sth));`

or

`struct sth *p = malloc(sizeof(struct sth *));`

or, `char ***p = malloc(sizeof(WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_HERE));`???

someday, some c guru told me that use the variable like this:

`struct sth *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));`

So i wrote some code:

```
void main() {
  int n = 1000000, i;
  char **p = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);    // works
  //char **p = malloc(sizeof(**p) * n);     // not work, segfault
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
          // p[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));   // works
          // p[i] = malloc(sizeof(p[i]));   // works
          // p[i] = malloc(sizeof(*p[i]));  // works
  }
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
          free(p[i]);
  }
  free(p);
}
```

still get confused, any easy way to remember?

Comment: In the cases you show, use `sizeof *p`. `sizeof **p` in your example fails because you should only do *one* dereference (to get the type that `p` points to).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/why-is-it-safer-to-use-sizeofpointer-in-malloc

Comment: BTW: it is not a parameter, since `sizeof` is not a function. It is a unary operator, so in `sizeof *p` , *p is its operand. And BTW2 `main()` should return int.

Comment: I'd note that the dup question's not accepted answer with far fewer upvotes fits better than the accepted one.

Comment: @Sato-- `malloc()` returns a pointer to something. You need to provide the size of that something (or a multiple of that size). With `struct sth *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` the operand to the `sizeof ` operator is the _type_ of the expression `*p`. Now, `p` is a pointer to `struct sth`, so `*p` has type `struct sth`. It works like this always, for any type. `struct sth *****p = malloc(sizeof *p);`: here `p` is a pointer to `(struct sth ****)`, so `*p` has type `(struct sth ****)`. You always need one dereference in the `sizeof` expression when using this idiom.

Comment: @Armali : yes, the accepted answer is rather poor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(struct sth)` is the size your struct takes in memory.

`sizeof(struct sth*)` is the size of a *pointer* to `struct sth` (usually 4 or 8 bytes); actually it's the size of *any*  pointer on your platform.

So you need:

```
struct sth *p = malloc(sizeof(struct sth));
```

But it is better to write:

```
struct sth *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

`sizeof(*p);` being the size of the object `p` points to and as `p` points to `struct sth`, `sizeof(*p)` is the same thing as `sizeof(struct sth)`.

Comment: what about : `struct sth **p1 = malloc(sizeof(??? )); struct sth ***p2 = malloc(sizeof(??));`

Comment: @Sato `struct sth **p1 = malloc(sizeof(**p));`. In this case you want to allocate a pointer to a pointer. But allocating just one pointer to a pointer is usually not very useful. Most of the time you would allocate space for more than one pointer to pointer, e.g:  `struct sth **p1 = malloc(sizeof(**p) * nb_of_pointers);`

Comment: but   `char **p = malloc(sizeof(**p) * n);`     // not work, segfault

Comment: If it segfaults, you need to post more code and tell us what you are _actually_ trying to do. You should probably post A new specific question including a [MCVE]

Comment: @MichaelWalz - your comment is incorrect.   `struct sth **p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1))` is still correct.   The difference is that it would also be necessary to follow that up with `*p1 = malloc(sizeof(**p1))` if double dereferencing `p1` (e.g. `**p1 = some_sth` or `(*p1)->member = something` is required.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `sizeof`, the C compiler computes the actual size of what you gave it. When you type `sizeof (*int)` for instance, you ask the compiler to compute the size of a ... **pointer** ! That is 4 or 8 bytes (32, 64 bits respectively) depending on your machine architecture.

However, if you type `sizeof (struct foo)` it will return the amount of bytes a struct of type `foo` would occupy in memory.

At some point you need to create enough memory for a struct and its values. So generally you want to pass `sizeof (struct foo)` to malloc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `*p` rule then in the case below you need to do

```
char **p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * n);
```

Even if you have `char ***p` you would still use

```
char ***p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * n);
```