# How to assign a temp value to a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, struct

So I have a 2d array of structs that I am storing data from a csv file. I am reading in the strings from the file then I want to assign their value in the 2d array as that string. So for example position [0][0] would be "red" and position [1][1] would be "blue" or something. The problem is that I am reading in the characters from the file and storing them in a temp string then I want to assign that temp string value to the current position I'm on. So I have the temp as "red" and I want [0][0] to be "red" then it reads more from the file and temp is now "blue" and I want [0][1] to be "blue". When I assign [0][0]=temp then [0][1]=temp they write over each other(since it is a pointer). I have tried strdup(temp) but that does not seem to fix the problem either they still re write over each other sometimes. I know I could use strcpy but for strcpy I have to have another string to copy it to so I tried that with just making a new char array each time, but that does not work either. It still gets written over. I know I could fix this problem if each time I assigned a value I created a new char array with a new name and pointed to that char array, but this is for a very large csv file so then I would have to create about 10 million char arrays and I do not know how to do that, and it seems like there should be a simpler way.

Any help is very much appreciated thanks!

```
struct node {
    char* value;
};

char temp[500];
struct node ** arrayofnodes[35];
for(int i=0; i<35; i++) {
    arrayofnodes[i] = malloc(test * sizeof (struct node));
    for(int j=0; j<test; j++) arrayofnodes[i][j] = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
}


//(all of this below happens inside a function because it is going to be called like 10 million times)
    arrayofnodes[row][count]->value=temp; //way 1
    arrayofnodes[row][count]->value=strdup(temp); //way 2
    char fun[500];
    strcpy(fun,temp);
    arrayofnodes[row][count]->value=fun;//way 3
```

Comment: Recommend you read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258647/why-is-it-safer-to-use-sizeofpointer-in-malloc

Comment: The `strdup()` approach is a viable one, and the only viable one of the three presented.  If it's not working for you then we would need to consider a [mcve] to do more than guess about why not.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayofnodes[i] = malloc(N * sizeof (struct node));` makes enough space for N structs. What you want is space for N struct pointers.

However I don't think that's your main problem.  Only "way 2" is valid - you do need to create storage for every new string you read.  "way 1" is re-using the `temp` storage, and "way 3" is re-using the 'fun' storage, which will be invalid as soon as you exit the function.

If "way 2" is not working for you, I'd look at the code generating `row` and `count`.  Are those indexes always less than `35` and `test` respectively?

Answer (score 0):

When using malloc or strdup, you need extra 16 bytes of space for management. 
When you allocate a lot of small memory, this extra space also takes up a lot of memory.
So consider own managing memory, or tcmalloc, jemalloc

#### Below is the test data:

gcc -otest test.c -Wall -O3 -g

```
[test_strdup] cost time: 1085247 us, use memory: 839.81 MB
[test_optimized] cost time: 394635 us, use memory: 411.71 MB
```

gcc -otest test.c -Wall -O3 -g -ltcmalloc

```
[test_strdup] cost time: 627160 us, use memory: 461.07 MB
[test_optimized] cost time: 397938 us, use memory: 422.85 MB
```

gcc -otest test.c -Wall -O3 -g -ljemalloc

```
[test_strdup] cost time: 749875 us, use memory: 481.77 MB
[test_optimized] cost time: 330825 us, use memory: 451.96 MB
```

#### Below is the test code

Just to compare the memory allocation, there is a memory leak in the test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

#define ROWS 35
#define COLS (1000*10000/ROWS)
#define MB   (1024*1024)
#define TEST_STR "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

struct node {
    char *value;
};

long current_time()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec * 1000000L + tv.tv_usec;
}

long current_usemem()
{
    FILE *fp;
    long resident = 0;

    fp = fopen("/proc/self/statm", "r");
    if (fp) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%*s %ld ", &resident) != 1)
            resident = 0;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    resident *= 4096;

    return resident;
}

void test_strdup()
{
    char temp[500];
    struct node **arrayofnodes[ROWS];
    int i, j;
    long start_time, end_time;
    long start_usemem, end_usemem;

    strcpy(temp, TEST_STR);
    start_usemem = current_usemem();
    start_time = current_time();

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        arrayofnodes[i] = (struct node **)malloc(COLS * sizeof(struct node *));
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            arrayofnodes[i][j] = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            arrayofnodes[i][j]->value = strdup(temp);
        }
    }

    end_time = current_time();
    end_usemem = current_usemem();
    printf("[%s] cost time: %ld us, use memory: %.2f MB\n",
           __FUNCTION__, end_time - start_time,
           (end_usemem - start_usemem) / 1024.0 / 1024);
}

struct memory_chunk {
    struct memory_chunk *next;
    char *cur;
    char *end;
    char buf[0];
};

struct memory_pool {
    struct memory_chunk *head;
};

void *pool_alloc(struct memory_pool *pool, size_t size)
{
    void *ret;
    struct memory_chunk *chunk;

    chunk = pool->head;
    if (chunk == NULL || chunk->cur + size >= chunk->end) {
        size_t len = (size < MB ? MB : size + sizeof(*chunk));
        chunk = (struct memory_chunk *)malloc(len);
        chunk->next = pool->head;
        chunk->end = (char *)chunk + len;
        chunk->cur = chunk->buf;
        pool->head = chunk;
    }

    ret = chunk->cur;
    chunk->cur += size;
    return ret;
}

char *pool_strdup(struct memory_pool *pool, const char *s)
{
    size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    void *ret = pool_alloc(pool, size);
    memcpy(ret, s, size);
    return ret;
}

void test_optimized()
{
    char temp[500];
    struct node ***arrayofnodes;
    int i, j;
    long start_time, end_time;
    long start_usemem, end_usemem;
    struct memory_pool pool = {NULL};

    strcpy(temp, TEST_STR);
    start_usemem = current_usemem();
    start_time = current_time();

    arrayofnodes = (struct node ** *)pool_alloc(&pool, ROWS * sizeof(struct node **));
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        arrayofnodes[i] = (struct node **)pool_alloc(&pool, COLS * sizeof(struct node *));
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            arrayofnodes[i][j] = (struct node *)pool_alloc(&pool, sizeof(struct node));
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            arrayofnodes[i][j]->value = pool_strdup(&pool, temp);
        }
    }

    end_time = current_time();
    end_usemem = current_usemem();
    printf("[%s] cost time: %ld us, use memory: %.2f MB\n",
           __FUNCTION__, end_time - start_time,
           (end_usemem - start_usemem) / 1024.0 / 1024);

}

int main()
{
    test_strdup();
    test_optimized();

    return 0;
}
```